# Python 'module' object is not callable with Font P

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

```
import os.path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.font as Font

try:
    from tkinter.ttk import Button, Scrollbar
except ImportError:
    pass

class Edit_save(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title('EditSave')
        self.root.geometry('+120+50')
        self.font_en = Font(self.root, size=12)
        self.font_text = Font(self.root,family="Helvetica",size=12,weight='normal')
        self.menubar = Menu(self.root, bg='purple')
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menubar)
```

My code is like that, the error message is

> 'module' object is not callable.

The question is `self.font_en = Font(self.root, size=12)`, Font is not callable.     How should I solve the problem?
Thanks very much!    And I am using Python 3.6.1

Comment: Is there a reason why you are wrapping an import within a try/except?

Comment: `import tkinter.font as Font` should probably be `from tkFont import Font`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm

Comment: I am using Python 3, so from tkFont import Font doesn't work. If I use Python 3 syntax: from tkinter import font, the error will become name 'Font' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter.font import Font
I figure out what the problem is, it should be imported this way.